# React-router how to redirect to server port

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I am using react router v4.

My React runs on port 3000, while express server runs on port 8080. The Redirect segment of the code below brings me to `localhost:3000/http://localhost:8080/auth/login`.

I have `"proxy": "localhost:8080"` in my React's package.json already. It doesn't work.

How can I redirect from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:8080/auth/login`?

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.fetchProducts();
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch> 
        <Route exact path='/cart' render={() => this.props.isLoggedIn ? 
          <Checkout /> : 
          <Redirect to='http://localhost:8080/auth/login' /> 
        } />
        <Route exact path='/user/account/profile' render={() => <Profile />} />
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <MainPage />} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

**Client's package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.6.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: As you already know from the this.props.isLoggedIn whether user is authenticated or not shouldn't it be this.props.isLoggedIn ? <Checkout /> : <Login />

or your login html is served by 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login'?

Comment: Yes my login html is served by 'localhost:8080/auth/login'. To add on, I have `"proxy": "localhost:8080"` in my React's package.json already. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't use react-router's Redirect to link to `/auth/login`, I changed `window.location.href` in a method and returned null.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.fetchProducts();
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  redirect = () => {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login';
    // maybe can add spinner while loading
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch> 
        <Route exact path='/cart' render={() => 
          this.props.isLoggedIn ? 
          <Checkout /> : 
          this.redirect()
        } />
        <Route exact path='/user/account/profile' render={() => <Profile />} />
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <MainPage />} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your package.json in the client folder (where the react files are).

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080"
  }
},
```

This will redirect your requests to the express server. Also change the Redirect to Redirect to `/auth/login`, you don't need to specify the full url.

Comment: I have ` "proxy": "localhost:8080"` in my React's package.json already. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add proxy in your package.json file of reactjs.

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

This will connect with nodejs server that is started on port 8080.

You should call api from client side using url

```
axios.post('/api/auth', {credentials}).then(res => res.data.user)
```

and the same time you have configure routes in nodejs using routes if you are using express

This should work.

Comment: I have `  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` in my React's package.json already. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think if your express server run in port 8080 than react router doesn't redirect you to "http://localhost:8080/auth/login" because it's an API that will authenticate you username/password credentials.

you can use fetch/axios to call your login api.

i think you are checking if user is already logged in before than redirect to login but i don't think you need to redirect to login page if user is already log in.